# Sorting of lists in number ranges

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

```
list = [1,2,,3,4,5,6,1,2,56,78,45,90,34]
range = ["0-25","25-50","50-75","75-100"]
```

I am coding in python. I want to sort a list of integers in range of numbers and store them in differrent lists.How can i do it?

I have specified my ranges in the the range list.

Comment: `list` and `range` as variablenames shadow build ins - do not use them as names for variables

Answer (score 4):

Create a dictionary with max-value of each *bin* as key. Iterate through your numbers and append them to the list that's the value of each *bin-key*:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,56,78,45,90,34]

# your range covers 25 a piece - and share start/endvalues.
# I presume [0-25[ ranges

def inRanges(data,maxValues):
    """Sorts elements of data into bins that have a max-value. Max-values are
    given by the list maxValues which holds the exclusive upper bound of the bins."""
    d = {k:[] for k in maxValues} # init all keys to empty lists
    for n in data:
        key = min(x for x in maxValues if x>n) # get key
        d[key].append(n) # add number
    return d


sortEm =  inRanges(l,[25,50,75,100])

print(sortEm)

print([ x for x in sortEm.values()])
```

Output:

```
 {25: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],  50: [25, 45, 34], 
  75: [56],                     100: [78, 90]}

 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2], [25, 45, 34], [56], [78, 90]]
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another stable bin approach for your special case (regular intervaled bins) would be to use a calculated key - this would get rid of the key-search in each step.

Stable search means the order of numbers in the list is the same as in the input data:

```
def inRegularIntervals(data, interval):
    """Sorts elements of data into bins of regular sizes.
    The size of each bin is given by 'interval'."""
    # init dict so keys are ordered - collection.defaultdict(list) 
    # would be faster - but this works for lists of a couple of
    # thousand numbers if you have a quarter up to one second ...

    # if random key order is ok, shorten this to d = {}    
    d = {k:[] for k in range(0, max(data), interval)}  
    for n in data:
        key = n // interval # get key
        key *= interval
        d.setdefault(key, [])
        d[key ].append(n) # add number
    return d
```

Use on random data:

```
from random import choices

data = choices(range(100), k = 50)
data.append(135) # add a bigger value to see the gapped keys

binned = inRegularIntervals(data, 25)
print(binned)
```

Output (\n and spaces added):

```
{ 0: [19, 9, 1, 0, 15, 22, 4, 9, 12, 7, 12, 9, 16, 2, 7], 
 25: [25, 31, 37, 45, 30, 48, 44, 44, 31, 39, 27, 36], 
 50: [50, 50, 58, 60, 70, 69, 53, 53, 67, 59, 52, 64], 
 75: [86, 93, 78, 93, 99, 98, 95, 75, 88, 82, 79], 
100: [], 
125: [135], }
```

---

To sort the binned lists in place, use

```
for k in binned:
    binned[k].sort()
```

to get:

```
{ 0: [0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 15, 16, 19, 22], 
 25: [25, 27, 30, 31, 31, 36, 37, 39, 44, 44, 45, 48], 
 50: [50, 50, 52, 53, 53, 58, 59, 60, 64, 67, 69, 70], 
 75: [75, 78, 79, 82, 86, 88, 93, 93, 95, 98, 99], 
100: [], 
125: [135]}
```